# pulling a github project into another github project

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a project on github which uses other repos in github. (I used JQuery , backbone.js , underscore.js in my project)
I want to pull those repos from github into my repo (possibly with their history).
And time to time I want to update those codes from their github repos. But I still want to commit them in my repo. Is that possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [git-submodule](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html).